# Как правильно написать слово "гештальттерапия"?

Tags: грамматика

Зашла на сайт психологического факультета МГУ. В первой же ссылке на статью вылезла "гештальт-терапия" (в тексте работы). Ссылку прилагаю: [Гештальт-терапевт - факультет психологии | msu.ru](http://www.psy.msu.ru/science/public/psy_prof/2_hestalt.html)

На сайте gramota.ru в словаре Лопатина указано слитное написание.
Хотелось бы найти еще подтверждения слитного написания.

И все-таки, "гештальт-терапия" или "гештальттерапия"? Чему (кому) верить?

Answer (score 1):

На сайте ГРАМОТА.РУ

...ТЕРАПИЯ [тэ] и [те], -и; ж. [греч. therapéia - лечение] Вторая часть сложных слов. Вносит зн.: лечение (внутренних болезней) тем способом, который указан в первой части слова. Диетотерапия, рентгенотерапия, физиотерапия.

Существует **большое количество разных видов терапии**, например: [Список видов терапии | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1148910)

В большинстве случаев сложное слово пишется **слитно**, при этом может использоваться соединительная гласная или первая основа может быть усеченной, то есть подбирается форма, удобная для прочтения и понимания слова.

**Дефисная форма** используется в тех случаях, когда графика слитного слова может вызвать затруднение: **гештальт-терапия, арт-терапия** (удвоение ТТ). Правила русского языка в общем случае позволяют выбрать удобную форму для подобных слов, в то же время это термин, который должен иметь **одну (закрепленную) форму письма.**

Поэтому правильное написание нужно проверять **по авторитетным источникам в этой области медицины, учитывать традицию применения этого названия**, например: [Московский Институт Гештальт-Терапии и Консультирования | gestalt-therapy.ru](http://gestalt-therapy.ru/)

**Примеры из научных трудов:**

1) Гештальт-подход в патогенетической психотерапии психогенных депрессий невротического уровня [Гештальт-подход в патогенетической психотерапии психогенных депрессий невротического уровня

Научная библиотека диссертаций и авторефератов disserCat http://www.dissercat.com/content/geshtalt-podkhod-v-patogeneticheskoi-psikhoterapii-psikhogennykh-depressii-nevroticheskogo-u#ixzz5CYXD74us | dissercat.com][3](http://www.dissercat.com/content/geshtalt-podkhod-v-patogeneticheskoi-psikhoterapii-psikhogennykh-depressii-nevroticheskogo-u)

2) Гештальт-терапевтическое воздействие на личность актеров в кризисных состояниях

[Гештальт-терапевтическое воздействие на личность актеров в кризисных состояниях | psibook.com](http://psibook.com/research/geshtalt-terapevticheskoe-vozdeystvie-na-lichnost-akterov-v-krizisnyh-sostoyaniyah.html)

Кстати, **арт-терапия в словарях пишется через дефис**
АРТ-ТЕРАПИЯ Метод лечения нервных и психических заболеваний средствами искусства и самовыражения в искусстве. Клиника арт-терапии.

Comment: _**по авторитетным источникам в этой области медицины**, например: http://gestalt-therapy.ru/_ === **Sibylla**, в Вашем _авторитетном_ источнике можно найти такие противоречащие одно другому написания: _"Московский Институт **Гештальт-Терапии** и Консультирования", 
 "Московский Институт **Гештальт-терапии** и Консультирования",

 "Семинар президента Европейской Ассоциации **Гештальт Терапии**"..._

Comment: Значит, надо найти другой  авторитетный источник, существуют, наверное, научные работы по этой теме.

Comment: _**Значит, надо найти другой авторитетный источник, существуют, наверное, научные работы по этой теме**_. === Существуют. Но в них разнобой. Авторы орфографических словарей пытаются упорядочить  написание: слитное написание принято и в РОС, и в _Орфографическом словаре современного русского языка_  Климовой... Ну и какие могут быть основания игнорировать эти словари?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Писать надо так, как в словарях. В данном случае - слитно.

Верить никому не надо. Во всяком случае словарь можно опровергать только словарем, а не сомнительным (с филологической точки зрения) источником.

Рассуждения на тему "как надо писать, если не знаешь, как надо" имеют весьма сомнительную ценность. Sibylla часто этим увлекается, я его в том поддержать не могу.

Никаких внутренних предубеждений против слитного написания не имею, дефисное мне кажется за уши притянутым. Никаких оговорок на случаи "затруднения" орфографические правила не содержат, это что-то из "виртуальной реальности".

Лопатин может ошибаться, не спорю, но ошибку надо доказать адекватным методом. Пока не увижу в другом словаре (желательно - тоже орфографическом) иного, буду считать слитное написание единственно правильным.

Comment: На кафедре психологического факультета дали ссылку на Большой психологический словарь (Мещеряков Б.Г., Зинченко В.П.): ГЕШТАЛЬТ-ТЕРАПИЯ (англ. gestalt therapy) — направление психотерапии, развившееся во 2-й пол. XX в., основывающееся на понятиях классической гештальт-психологии, в частности, на понятиях гештальта, фигуры и фона и на теории поля К. Левина. В то же время в Г.-т. можно найти элементы самых разных психологических и философских течений — психоанализа, экзистенциализма, психодрамы, феноменологии, дзэн-буддизма и др.

Comment: @Rin  *ссылку на Большой психологический словарь* - да, это некий аргумент посильнее написания на сайте. Но все равно общеязыковые нормы орфографии "ведомственными" документы не устанавливают. Можете попробовать задать этот вопрос на "Грамоте" (с указанием ссылок на оба словаря), там в принципе прямая связь с Лопатиным. Если захотят - раскрутят клубок, но последнее время от них вменяемые ответы стали большой редкостью, так что без гарантий. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/add-question

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к вопросу! Позже буду раскручивать)